# How to resolve requested variants error when upgrading macports

Tags: macports

After reinstalling macports on MacOS after upgrading from High Sierra (darwin17) to Mojave (darwin18), while reinstalling previously installed ports using the the restore_ports.tcl script provided by macports, I am receiving:

> Error: Requested variants "" do not match those the build was started with: "+universal".

I understand that I can resolve this error on a case-by-case basis by passing the +x86_64 argument to the macports install command. The problem is that I am attempting to reinstall my many ports using the restore_ports.tcl script rather than installing them by hand.

Is there some way to fix this error when running the restore_ports script? Can I modify the installed ports text file passed to the script? Is there an architecture argument I can pass to the script?

Comment: Maybe research here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, for some reason apple.stackexchange.com wasn't on my radar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for comment from jdv. Over at apple.stackexchange.com I encountered an unrelated macports question that mentioned macports.conf. I found that the *universal_archs* flag in my macports.conf was set to *x86_64 i386*. Removed the *i386* and now ports are installing fine.